# How to customize IDP login page

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I am using WSO2 as IDP and my SP is just a simple web app deployed in tomcat using spring framework.

I want to get the username password from SP (webapp) then when i hit login button, i want to pass on the user/passwd to IDP and get authorized. How to implement this requirement?

Thanks!

Comment: In SAML the SP never sees the username/password. SAML Web Browser Single Sign On (WBSSO) is one of the more common SAML profiles the SP needs to implement in order to work with an IdP

Answer (score 0):

SAML standard does not allow Username/Password credentials to be passed from the Service Provider (SP) to the Identity Provider (IdP) for authentication. You can however, send the username in the form of  element as part of the AuthnRequest to be prepopulated by the IdP login screen.

Comment: Thanks for your response George.. Is there a way to customize it?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not familiar with the WSO2 IdP